# Trying to install react-native-location but erroring out

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

I have installed `react-native-location` by doign yarn add `react-native-location`

Keep getting the following errors when trying to use it according their documents:

`Could not find the RNLocation native module. Have you correctly linked react-native-location and rebuilt your app?`

`Invariant Violation: new NativeEventEmitter() requires a non-null argument.`

`Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.A module failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.registerComponent wasn't called.`

My usage:

```
import { Button, SafeAreaView, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React, { useLayoutEffect, useState } from 'react'

import RNLocation from 'react-native-location';

RNLocation.configure({
//  distanceFilter: null
})
interface Props {
    navigation: any,
  };

const LocationNotification: React.FC<Props> = ({ navigation}) => {
    
const permissionHandle = async () => {

    console.log('here')


    let permission = await RNLocation.checkPermission({
        ios: "whenInUse",
        android: {
          detail: "coarse",
          rationale: {
            title: "We need to access your location",
            message: "We use your location to show where you are on the map",
            buttonPositive: "OK",
            buttonNegative: "Cancel"
          }
        }
    });
    console.log(permission)

}
return(
    <SafeAreaView>
    <View style={{marginTop: 10, padding: 10, borderRadius: 10, width: '40%'}}>
        <Button
        title="Get Location"
        />
    </View>
    <Text>Latitude: </Text>
    <Text>Longitude: </Text>
    <View style={{marginTop: 10, padding: 10, borderRadius: 10, width: '40%'}}>
        <Button
        title="Send Location"
        onPress={permissionHandle}
        />
      </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
)
}

export default LocationNotification;
```

Tried removing `node_modules`, `yarn lock`, nothing seems to work, I just cannot seem to move forward.

Do I need something like Cocoapods to make it work or something?

Comment: have you already tried linking the library.

react-native link <library_name>

Comment: tried now, still same error unfortunately

Comment: `cd ios; pod install` have you installed Pods ?

Comment: Delete the app, close the metro server, start it again with "npm start --reset-cache" and then build the app again. it is most likely a cache issue